# My PHP includes won't appear

Tags: php, html, include

I'm trying to include the header and footer of my site as PHP include files, but can't seem to get it to work. I've changed the index.html to index.php. Then, I removed the header and footer and replaced them with PHP include statements, like so:  
`<?php include 'includes/header.php';?>`  
In the PHP include files, the code looks like this:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-6">
                <p>&copy; 2018 Ace in the Hole</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

This is just the HTML code for the footer that I'm inserting into the index.php. Is there a PHP statement that should be used here to pull this information? Like an echo statement?  
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's your folder structure? I presume that snippet is in a folder called "includes", and that folder is in the same folder as the main file?

Comment: if you're not going to use any php directives from an html file, use `file_get_contents()` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Interesting @FunkFortyNiner is it much better performance than an include? Definitely makes sense, though not sure when I've last not had PHP in my includes as well!

Comment: @Dammeul I use that function every once in a while where I need to pull something off a file from somewhere, tucked neatly outside of the public area ;-)

Comment: @Dammeul far as performance goes; I doubt there'd be anything significant enough to tell.

Comment: Yes, that's the folder structure. Main Folder > index.php, includes > header.php, footer.php

Answer (score 0):

Check the path of the included file
You must run the using a server like wamp,xampp etc

sample index.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/header.php';
?>
```

sample header.php file in the "includes" folder

```
<footer>
    <div class="container"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-6">
                <p>&copy; 2018 Ace in the Hole</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where there error was in my paths, but I moved the includes out of their folder and onto the same level as the index.php (not ideal, bu it will do for now). They work fine this way, called in a statement like this:

```
<?php include 'header.php';?>
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Take in mind include references directories, not urls, for instance

If you have include_me.php in /var/www/html/includes/, to include it in a file located in /var/www/html/ you should:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/includes/include_me.php");
```

also I recommend you to check your apache log looking for messages:

centos
/var/log/httpd/error_log

ubuntu/debian
By default, /var/log/apache2/error.log.

This can be configured in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Hope it helps you

Comment: Error log shows 'include(includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/cas222/template/template.php on line 27'

Comment: So where is your includes directory? If it isn't below the template directory that would explain the error.

Comment: It is below the template directory. Folder structure goes as follows: template > index.php and includes folder (same level) > header.php and footer.php inlcudes

Comment: Kyle Barnes, you must follow your tree structure, the post shows an example, no a literal solution for your environment, if you have in the same folder a.php and b.php, you can include('b.php') in a.php directly, but if b.php is inside a folder called 'sample' you must change include('b.php') to include('sample/b.php')